# Laravel 5 JWT issue

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-authorization

|Hi, I'm using Laravel 5.2 , trying to get JWT (https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) working, so the problem is that I can't catch exception, I'd like to send a custom response in case of an error , but I can't catch it, phpstorm suggests that namespace is wrong `Tymon\JWTAuth\**Exceptions**\TokenInvalidException`, but I went to vendor folder and checked the namespace is right, here is the code:

```
    try {

        if (!$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }
    } catch (Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e) {

        return ['token_invalid'];

    }
    return $user;
```

so the `return ['token_invalid'];` is not executed when I missmutch the token, it just throws exception on the whole screen

Answer (score 0):

ops should have used `JWTException` as a namespace here is the working code:

```
try {
    if (!$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()) {
        return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
    }
} catch (JWTException $e) {
    return ['token_invalid'];
}

return $user;
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot `backslash`

```
\Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e
```

Comment: I guess so. You can rather use \Exception to catch the exception although Typed exception are preferred.